# How to do an update cascade in MongoDB using Kundera

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, entity, kundera

I'm using Kundera to do the persistence in MongoDB. In my model, I have entities classes that have a set of variables, some of these are List of another entities classes, and so on. For example, an entity class named RecordVersion that has a list of the entity class Record, which in turn has a list of the entity class AuxiliarData. 
Something like this: RecordVersion > Record > AuxiliarData > References

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recordVersion", schema = "TestDB@records")
public class RecordVersion {
  @Id 
  @Column(name="idRecordVersion")
  private String idRecordVersion;

  //others variables..      

  @OneToMany (cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER")
  @JoinColumn(name="idRecordVersion")
  private List<Record> record = Lists.newArrayList();
```

For Record

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Record", schema = "TestDB@records")
 public class Record {
    @Id 
    @Column(name="idRecord")
    private String idRecord;

    //others variables..

    @OneToMany (cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="idRecord")
    private List<AuxiliarData> auxiliarData = Lists.newArrayList();
```

For AuxiliarData

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "AuxiliarData", schema = "TestDB@records")
 public class AuxiliarData {
    @Id 
    @Column(name="idAuxiliarData")
    private String idAuxiliarData;

    //others variables..

    @OneToMany (cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="idAuxiliarData")
    private List<References> references = Lists.newArrayList();
```

I can persist in mongoDB,complete data of RecordVersion, with all the nesting until Reference, but, I can't make an update for that record of RecordVersion, after, for example adding more Records, for a specific RecordVersion in the collection of Mongo.

I tried with em.merge(someRecordVersion), but didn´t work.

Comment: any error shown after `em.merge()` ?

Comment: Which version of Kundera are you using?

Comment: @dev I'm using kundera-mongo 3.0 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>kundera-mongo</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
 </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

By default [WriteConcern](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/)  for MongoDB is **ACKNOWLEDGED** same is used in Kundera-MongoDB (*means it will show errors for the duplicate primary key, etc.*)

You can avoid these error by setting WriteConcern to UNACKNOWLEDGED using em level property:

```
 em.setProperty(MongoDBClientProperties.WRITE_CONCERN, WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED);
```

Sample code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("records");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();        
em.setProperty(MongoDBClientProperties.WRITE_CONCERN, WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED);
RecordVersion recVersion = new RecordVersion();
//setting children
em.merge(recVersion);
```